# Jquery/Ember object iteration

Tags: jquery, json, ember.js

I have an ember app with that shows jobs positions. Im trying to filter those jobs positions depending of  the ip location.

Im using geonames for searching the state based in the latitude and longitude of the request.

The [api request](http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=25.631590600000003&lng=-100.3019204&username=demo&style=full) is made in

```
var state=StateAdapter.getState(location);
```

Then, i print the result

```
 console.log(state);
```

I have this returning object state:

```
Object {readyState:1 }
abort: ( statusText )
always: ()
complete: ()
done: ()
error: ()
fail: ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ()
getResponseHeader: ( key )
overrideMimeType: ( type )
pipe: ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
progress: ()
promise: ( obj )
readyState: 4
responseJSON: Object
responseText: "{"geonames":     [{"adminCode2":"039","countryName":"Mexico","adminCode1":"19","lng":"-100.29265","adminName2":"Monterrey","fcodeName":"populated place","adminName3":"","distance":"1.07626","timezone":{"dstOffset":-5,"gmtOffset":-6,"timeZoneId":"America/Monterrey"},"adminName4":"","adminName5":"","name":"Norte de Monterrey","fcode":"PPL","geonameId":9072770,"asciiName":"Norte de Monterrey","lat":"25.63646","population":0,"adminName1":"Nuevo León","countryId":"3996063","adminId1":"3522542","fclName":"city, village,...","elevation":0,"countryCode":"MX","adminId2":"8582459","toponymName":"Norte de Monterrey","fcl":"P","continentCode":"NA"}]}"
setRequestHeader: ( name, value )
state: ()
status: 200
statusCode: ( map )
statusText: "OK"
success: ()
then: ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
__proto__: Object
```

But when i do this:

```
$.each( state, function( key, value ) {
console.log("state["+key +"]" + value);
});
```

Console doesnt print readyState, responseJSON, responseText, status nor statusText. I need responseText result to filter my model.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks guys.

Comment: Use JSON.parse(state.responseText) to get the response object.

Comment: state.responseText is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API response is async. This example would work.

```
$.ajax("http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON", {
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: {
    lat: 25.631590600000003,
    lng: 100.3019204,
    username: "demo",
    style: "full"
  }
}).done(function(response){
  $.each(response.geonames, function(index, geoname){
    console.log(geoname);
  });      
});
```

You cannot simply return the ajax request, it won't immediately have your data. Instead you would use a promise or a callback. So for instance if you want to wrap that with a promise you could do:

```
function geoNames(loc){
  console.log(loc);
  return $.ajax("http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON", {
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
      lat: loc.lat,
      lng: loc.lng,
      username: "demo",
      style: "full"
    }
  })
}
```

Then:

```
var loc = {lat: 25.631590600000003, lng: -100.3019204};
geoNames(loc).done(function(response){
  $.each(response.geonames, function(index, geoname){
    $("body").append("<p>" + geoname + "</p>");
  });      
});
```

Or with a callback:

```
function geoNames(loc,  callback){
  console.log(loc);
  return $.ajax("http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON", {
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
      lat: loc.lat,
      lng: loc.lng,
      username: "demo",
      style: "full"
    }
  }).done(callback)
}
```

Then:

```
var loc = {lat: 25.631590600000003, lng: -100.3019204};
geoNames(loc, function(response){
  $.each(response.geonames, function(index, geoname){
    $("body").append("<p>" + geoname + "</p>");
  });      
});
```

Another wholly separate issue is that you shouldn't use `location` as a variable name. `window.location` is a browser specific global variable and isn't always overridable. Use `loc` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, StateAdapter only calls the geonames API. When i try to implement your solution, i have undefined error in apiResponse.responseJSON.

Comment: Right, I see you are actually logging two things. I think you might be confused about the async nature of ajax calls. consider the above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, you're awesome!